# Trajectory of a body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

If the velocity vector and acceleration vector are given,how can we find the trajectory of the body.

Example:. V=(4i+4j)m/s and  A= (-20j)m/s2

Comment: [Simple version](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations), and the [more complex (and complete) version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion)

Comment: -1. No research effort. Easily googled, eg http://formulas.tutorvista.com/physics/projectile-motion-formula.html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the velocity vector given is the initial velocity, you can use the kinematic equations $x = x_0 + v_x + .5a_xt^2$ and $y = y_0 + v_yt - .5gt^2$ to calculate the path in the x and y direction. Then add them together to get the trajectory, trajectory = $(x^2+y^2)^.5$.

Comment: By the way, $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the initial positions.